# How to convert string of JSON array to array of object in PHP

Tags: php, json

suppose I have

```
$obj = "[{'A':'a1','B':2,'C':'c1'},{'A':'a2','B':2,'C':'c2'}]"
```

And I want to convert it to array of object.

```
obj[0](
A => 'a1'
B => 2
C => 'c1'
)
```

How can I do?

Comment: Did you try something like `$ob = json_decode($obj);` ?

Comment: That is not valid json so you would probably need to parse it manually.

Comment: Your quotes are exchanged. If it is : `$obj = '[{"A":"a1","B":2,"C":"c1"},{"A":"a2","B":2,"C":"c2"}]';` you can very well convert to object. otherwise you need to parse it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_replace()` to change single quotes to double quote for proper json string.

Then use `json_decode()` to convert it into array.

```
$obj = "[{'A':'a1','B':2,'C':'c1'},{'A':'a2','B':2,'C':'c2'}]";
$newobj = str_replace("'", '"', $obj);
$arr = json_decode($newobj);
print_r($arr);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [A] => a1
            [B] => 2
            [C] => c1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [A] => a2
            [B] => 2
            [C] => c2
        )

)
```

**Check Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/574099)**

Comment: Use above code to convert your string to json and from json string to array. @ThSorn

Comment: OP needs object not array. Remove that `true` from `json_decode`